# Cannot GET / DELETE Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this script with which I'm trying to POST, GET and DELETE some stuff.
When I try POST or GET, the right messages are logged, but when I try DELETE, I get the following error:

> Cannot GET /del_user

The URL I'm using is http://127.0.0.1:8081/del_user

What can be wrong in here?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// This responds with "Hello World" on the homepage
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   console.log("Got a GET request for the homepage");
   res.send('Hello GET');
})

// This responds a POST request for the homepage
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
   console.log("Got a POST request for the homepage");
   res.send('Hello POST');
})

// This responds a DELETE request for the /del_user page.
app.delete('/del_user', function (req, res) {
   console.log("Got a DELETE request for /del_user");
   res.send('Hello DELETE');
})

// This responds a GET request for the /list_user page.
app.get('/list_user', function (req, res) {
   console.log("Got a GET request for /list_user");
   res.send('Page Listing');
})

// This responds a GET request for abcd, abxcd, ab123cd, and so on
app.get('/ab*cd', function(req, res) {   
   console.log("Got a GET request for /ab*cd");
   res.send('Page Pattern Match');
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Comment: You're trying to perform a GET on `/del_user`. You need to perform a DELETE.

Comment: Your problem is with the code you are using to try to make the DELETE request, it is making a GET request.

Comment: Are you accessing it manually from the browser or jquery? It should use `delete` verb.

Comment: Your code is fine. Show us the client side. Like what @MikeC highlighed, the error you are getting suggests that you are doing a GET on a DEL end point.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing the `app.delete` to `app.get` and then placing the required remove statement inside the `app.get`. Something like this :-

```
app.get('/delete/:userId', (req, res) => {
    Users.remove({ _id: req.params.userId }, (error, posts) => {
        if (error) {
            console.warn(error);
        }
        else {
            data = posts
            res.render("delete", {"data": data})
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That's what I've done seconds before finding this answer . Trusted !

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're binding the `/del_user` URL to the HTTP `DELETE` method.
So all you need to do is specify the `DELETE` method in your application or in Postman.
If you're not using it, it's an App in Google Chrome and you might want to download it, it makes your life a LOT easier ;)

Also, since the HTTP method is already declared to be `DELETE`, there is no need to specify it in the URL.
This is part of the [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Relationship_between_URL_and_HTTP_methods) working.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using AJAX to try your code, you need to specify the method, which is delete.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/del_user",
    type: "DELETE"
});
```